# Transformar Query em Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Preciso transformar essa query em Linq:

```
select B.Nome
from Gestor A 
inner join Entidade B on A.UniaoEntidadeId = b.EntidadeId
group by B.Nome
HAVING COUNT(A.EscolaId) > 0
```

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Answer (score 3):

Não posso testar, mas deve ser algo parecido com isto:

```
from g in db.Gestor
join e in db.Entidade on g.UniaoEntidadeId equals e.EntidadeId
group g by g.Nome into grpNome
where grpNome.Count() > 0
select grpNome.Key
```